# Rails routes enforce controller inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

Is there a way to enforce that a controller inherits from another one in the route declaration? For example, if class B was a subclass of class A, allow it to use the route. Something like this?

```
match '/login/:controller', :constraint => { :inherits => A }
```

**Update**

As a more concrete example, I have an OAuthController that accepts logins from several sources. Let's say Google, Facebook, and Twitter. I have a GoogleController, FacebookController, and TwitterController that are all subclasses of OAuthController. So right now I accept the following routes:

```
/login/google
/login/facebook
/login/twitter
```

I might add or remove others at any time but I don't want to change my route. I also only want the :controller to be a subclass of :OAuthController. Is there a way to enforce that?

Comment: When you say allow it to use the route, what exactly do you want to say. As an example, post a route that you want based on your req.

Comment: It's like Generics with constraints. I've updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that there is support out of the box for what you want to reach. However, there may be a way to go for. Have a look at ["Rails Guides to Routing, Advanced Constraints"](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints). It uses a [request object](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-request-object) which is not exactly what you want to have, but may be sufficient.

The idea goes like that:

- Implement a constraint with the necessary methods.
- In the method `matches?(request)`, do what you want to prove.
- Integrate it by adding the route constraint:

  ```
  match "*path" => "login/:action",
    :constraints => LoginConstraint.new
  ```

This is the code for the implementation:

```
class BlacklistConstraint
  def initialize
    ... # necessary initialization here
  end

  def matches?(request)
    ... # Here is your check that returns true or false
  end
end
```